# JQuery not filter

Tags: jquery

```
function() {
              $(this).animate({ width: 130 }, 300, function() { });
        });
```

I wanna animate only those li's whose width is not 160

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
$('li').filter(function() { return $(this).width() != 160 }).animate({ width: 130 }, 300, function() { });
```

For readability:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].width = function(e, ix, match) { return $(e).width() == match[3]; };
```

You may then, at any point, do:

```
$('li:not(:width(160))').animate({ width: 130 }, 300, function() { });
```